# Puppet (err): Found 1 dependency cycle + cycles.dot file

Tags: puppet, devops

I am running this cmd:

```
puppet apply --environment split4 -l C:\Puppet_logs\log.log C:\ProgramData\PuppetLabs\code\environments\split4\manifests\bl.pp
```

This is the code which is running:

```
  service {
    $name :
      ensure => stopped,
      enable => true;
  } ->
 tidy { $bl_deployment_folder :
   rmdirs => true,
   recurse => 1,
  # notify => Service[$name],
   matches => ['*.dll','*.jar','*.exe','*.test','*.utd'];
  # subscribe   => File[$bl_deployment_folder];

} ->
file {
    #set the BL run time folder and update it according to the source folder
    $bl_deployment_folder :
      ensure    => directory,
      source    => $bl_source_folder,
      recurse   => true,
      ignore    => "AlisConfig.ini";
     }
```

**According to this code, I would like to:**

- Stop the tomcat service
- Clean the specific files that I mentioned
- copy files from source to my directory ($bl_deployment_folder)

Unfortunately, when I'm running it, it throws this error:

```
+0300 Puppet (err): Found 1 dependency cycle:
(File[//my-server/C$/BL/ALIS_PUPPET/AAppData.dll] => Tidy[\\my-server\C$\BL\ALIS_PUPPET] => File[\\my-server\C$\BL\ALIS_PUPPET] => File[//my-server/C$/BL/ALIS_PUPPET/AAppData.dll])
Cycle graph written to C:/ProgramData/PuppetLabs/puppet/cache/state/graphs/cycles.dot.
Puppet (err): Failed to apply catalog: One or more resource dependency cycles detected in graph
```

The circles.dot file is attached:

```html
digraph Resource_Cycles { label = "Resource Cycles" "File[//my-server/C$/BL/ALIS_PUPPET/AAppData.dll]" -> "Tidy[\\my-server\C$\BL\ALIS_PUPPET]" -> "File[\\my-server\C$\BL\ALIS_PUPPET]" -> "File[//my-server/C$/BL/ALIS_PUPPET/AAppData.dll]" "File[//my-server/C$/BL/ALIS_PUPPET/AAppData.dll]"
-> "Tidy[\\my-server\C$\BL\ALIS_PUPPET]" -> "File[\\my-server\C$\BL\ALIS_PUPPET]" -> "File[//my-server/C$/BL/ALIS_PUPPET/obj_data_client.dll]" -> "Tidy[\\my-server\C$\BL\ALIS_PUPPET]" "File[//my-server/C$/BL/ALIS_PUPPET/AAppData.dll]" -> "Tidy[\\my-server\C$\BL\ALIS_PUPPET]"
-> "File[\\my-server\C$\BL\ALIS_PUPPET]" -> "File[//my-server/C$/BL/ALIS_PUPPET/obj_data_policy.dll]" -> "Tidy[\\my-server\C$\BL\ALIS_PUPPET]" "File[//my-server/C$/BL/ALIS_PUPPET/AAppData.dll]" -> "Tidy[\\my-server\C$\BL\ALIS_PUPPET]" -> "File[\\my-server\C$\BL\ALIS_PUPPET]"
-> "File[//my-server/C$/BL/ALIS_PUPPET/obj_exceptions.dll]" -> "Tidy[\\my-server\C$\BL\ALIS_PUPPET]" "File[//my-server/C$/BL/ALIS_PUPPET/AAppData.dll]" -> "Tidy[\\my-server\C$\BL\ALIS_PUPPET]" -> "File[\\my-server\C$\BL\ALIS_PUPPET]" -> "File[//my-server/C$/BL/ALIS_PUPPET/obj_metadata.dll]"
-> "Tidy[\\my-server\C$\BL\ALIS_PUPPET]" "File[//my-server/C$/BL/ALIS_PUPPET/AAppData.dll]" -> "Tidy[\\my-server\C$\BL\ALIS_PUPPET]" -> "File[\\my-server\C$\BL\ALIS_PUPPET]" -> "File[//my-server/C$/BL/ALIS_PUPPET/obj_metadata_product.dll]" -> "Tidy[\\my-server\C$\BL\ALIS_PUPPET]"
"File[//my-server/C$/BL/ALIS_PUPPET/AAppData.dll]" -> "Tidy[\\my-server\C$\BL\ALIS_PUPPET]" -> "File[\\my-server\C$\BL\ALIS_PUPPET]" -> "File[//my-server/C$/BL/ALIS_PUPPET/obj_services.dll]" -> "Tidy[\\my-server\C$\BL\ALIS_PUPPET]" "File[//my-server/C$/BL/ALIS_PUPPET/AAppData.dll]"
-> "Tidy[\\my-server\C$\BL\ALIS_PUPPET]" -> "File[\\my-server\C$\BL\ALIS_PUPPET]" -> "File[//my-server/C$/BL/ALIS_PUPPET/objects.dll]" -> "Tidy[\\my-server\C$\BL\ALIS_PUPPET]" "File[//my-server/C$/BL/ALIS_PUPPET/AAppData.dll]" -> "Tidy[\\my-server\C$\BL\ALIS_PUPPET]"
-> "File[\\my-server\C$\BL\ALIS_PUPPET]" -> "File[//my-server/C$/BL/ALIS_PUPPET/xerces-c_2_6.dll]" -> "Tidy[\\my-server\C$\BL\ALIS_PUPPET]" "File[//my-server/C$/BL/ALIS_PUPPET/AAppData.dll]" -> "Tidy[\\my-server\C$\BL\ALIS_PUPPET]" -> "File[\\my-server\C$\BL\ALIS_PUPPET]"
-> "File[//my-server/C$/BL/ALIS_PUPPET/xmltools.dll]" -> "Tidy[\\my-server\C$\BL\ALIS_PUPPET]" }
```

What do I need to do to fix this problem?

I appreciate your help!

Thanks!

Comment: Do you see how the graph of the cycle contains `File` and `Tidy` resources whose names use backslashes, and others whose names use forward slashes?  Some of them even designating the same file?  Start by using forward slashes instead of backslashes in the titles of your `Tidy` and `File` resources, so that they use the same convention as the resources they automatically generate.

Comment: Or, if the point is to get rid of all files other than those managed by your recursive `File` resource, then a better solution would be to get rid of the `Tidy` altogether and instead turn on [the `File`'s `purge` option](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/types/file.html#file-attribute-purge).

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the [`tidy` resource deletes files by creating `file` resources](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/types/tidy.html) in `$bl_deployment_folder`. Each of those `file` resources will autorequire its parent directory `file` resource, in this case `$bl_deployment_folder`. The `->` between the `tidy` and the directory `file` implies that `$bl_deployment_folder` requires the `tidy` `file` resources in it, and so you have a cycle.

Unfortunately, the upshot is that you can't have a `file` require a `tidy` on the same directory.

In this case, I'd suggest just removing the dependency and letting the tidy run in its own time.

I'd also note that this Puppet manifest feels very procedural. Puppet is really, really bad at "do this, then this, then that" type scripts. It wants to operate in a declarative "tell me what the final state is, and I'll sort it out" way. Trying to use it procedurally is just painful and isn't to be recommended.